# Does move constructor only affect the memory space pointed to by the pointer member of the class？

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

For example, this Code:

```
struct President  
{  
    std::string name;  
    std::string country;  
    int year;  

    President(std::string p_name, std::string p_country, int p_year)  
        : name(std::move(p_name)), country(std::move(p_country)), year(p_year)  
    {  
        std::cout << "--constructed\n";  
    }
    /*
    President(const President& other)
        : name(std::move(other.name)), country(std::move(other.country)), year(other.year)
    */
    President(const President& other)
        : name(other.name), country(other.country), year(other.year)
    {
        std::cout << "--copy constructed\n";
    }
    President(President&& other)  
        : name(std::move(other.name)), country(std::move(other.country)), year(other.year)  
    {
        std::cout << "--moved\n";  
    }  
    ~President()
    {  
        cout << "\n"<< &name << " " << country << endl;
        std::cout << "--destruct\n";  
    }
    President& operator=(const President& other);  
};
```

Whether it is a move constructor or a copy constructor, they will cause the values of the three data members to be stored in the new memory, and the old memory will be released.

And my meaning is right?

Comment: *"the old memory will be released"* - what memory are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And my meaning is right?

Sorry, no.  Your move constructor will work as you describe, in that it will 'steal' the contents of the `name` and `country` member variables from `other`, but the copy constructor will not.  `std::move` does nothing with a `const` object and you should remove it from your copy constructor.  After all, the operative word is `copy`, right?

It's worth noting that you don't need to write your own copy or move constructors at all here ('rule of zero').  The default constructors synthesized by the compiler will work just fine.  Oh, and `std::move` on a primitive type such as an `int` also does nothing - the variable will just be copied whether you include it or not.

Comment: Write own copy or move constructors at all here. Because I want to use `cout` to determine which constructor to call. So how does the copy constructor execute? Mainly if you copy a temporary quantity, such as `President A( B ) // B is a President class type object`

Comment: You can test this out for yourself using one of the many online compilers out there, e.g. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/).